# Visual Studio Ultimate - UI actions - copy and paste?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests

I'm creating a number of test-cases from a single CodedUITest recording, to use on multiple URL's.

In the main, the content at URL's are (almost) identical. Where one does differ from the other, it is usually a single instance of a UI action. Pre and subsequent actions are the same.

To save time, and for ease of maintenance, where one does differ from the other I'd simply like to be able to copy one UI action from an existing and know to work entity, and the delete the failing entity and replace it with this copied one.

I can see it is easy to delete an action......but not to be able to copy one, or paste it.

Is there a way to do this?

Basically, the URL's are (supposed to be) replications of the same database, for which lots of test-cases are generated. Being able to do this to the test-cases at will, would MASSIVELY improve maintenance of many existing test-cases, without having to do a re-recording of each one of them.

Comment: I don't understand why you have gotten so angry at someone who was genuinely trying to help you, but please don't badger them to delete their answer and please don't deface your own question.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than recording several actions in one big Coded UI action method, record several smaller action methods then just make copies of the `[TestMethod]` and include/exclude calls of the small actions as needed.

If you have the big action method already recorded then you can use the "split method" command to divide it into two pieces. Repeated splitting should produce the required smaller methods. Note you will probable want to rename the methods after splitting as the new names are not pretty. Both split and rename are available via context menu and command icons in the UIMap Editor.